# jquery: change css if header is clicked

Tags: jquery

i would like to add one more thing to my code. right now i have styled h3 like this:

```
h3:before {
font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
content: "\35";
float:left;
}
```

i would like to change this line  `content: "\35";` to `content: "\38";` when header is clicked and content is opened.

html:

```
<h3>PS elementum justo ligula</h3>
<div>elementum justo ligula, interdum scelerisque.
<button>Close</button>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("h3").click(function () {
$(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `content:` css as the some attribute value of that element.

Changes Made

1. Added attribute **show-content** to the element
   `<h3 show-content="35">PS elementum justo ligula</h3>`
2. changed content css to
   `content: attr(show-content);`
3. changed js to update this custom attribute on click
    `$(this).attr('show-content','38');`

JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/bc60n7sy/

Answer (score 1):

Change class instead.

```
h3:before {
font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
content: "\35";
float:left;
}

h3.alt:before {
font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
content: "\38";
float:left;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$("h3").click(function () {
$(this).addClass("alt");
$(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: @Gallex Well good. It would be nice if you upvote and accept the answer. :)